# chips content needed to be updated after I click the content in the menu

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to implement chips functionality similar to google flights.
- right now when I click the chips the menu is opening up. here sports is a chips
- but when I click profile the sports text in the chip should be updated with profile text with cross icon.
- I tried by passing event, but I dont get the clicked li in the console.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below

my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/40mmrl9059

example

https://www.google.fr/flights#flt=AUS./m/02_286.2018-11-16*/m/02_286.AUS.2018-11-20;c:USD;e:1;a:STAR_ALLIANCE*STAR_ALLIANCE;sd:1;t:f

```
<WithState>
              {({ anchorEl, updateAnchorEl }) => {
                const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
                const handleClose = e => {
                  console.log("handleClose --->", e);
                  updateAnchorEl(null);
                };

                return (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <Chip
                      onClick={event => {
                        console.log(
                          "event.currentTarget--->",
                          event.currentTarget
                        );
                        updateAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
                      }}
                      label="Sports"
                      className={classes.chip}
                    />

                    <Chip
                      label="Sports Staus Active"
                      onDelete={handleDelete}
                      className={classes.chip}
                      color="primary"
                    />
```

Comment: I hope I understood your question correctly.  Have you tried event.currentTarget?  logging the event object will do you little good - but logging a key in the object should get you what you're looking for.  See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Comment: @LukeT hey thanks for your reply...I tried in sandbox but its not working...can you update here https://codesandbox.io/s/40mmrl9059

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the sandbox.  Try [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ykmrrmrwj9).

Comment: hey still its not working...can you update the comments in the code...it will be helpful for future use

Comment: Oh, check the console - I thought you were looking to target the 'li' when you clicked on Profile?

Comment: hey can you help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750902/passing-enter-key-event-completion-from-the-chip-component-to-the-tab-component